# Condition number of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, condition-number

Given a block matrix:
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
D & E^T \\
E & 0
\end{bmatrix} ,
$$
where $D$ is a diagonal, positive entry matrix and $E$ is an incidence matrix of a graph, how is the condition number of A related to that of D?
I tried to exploit the SVD decomposition of A to find a relation with D but I didn't find any interesting conclusion.

Comment: This [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221326/is-the-condition-number-of-a-2x2-block-symmetric-matrix-greater-than-the-condition-number-of-its-upper-left-hand-block%3F) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532948/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-inverse-of-the-upper-block-of-a-matrix-when-the-whole-inverse-is-known%3F) that I found on SearchOnMat help you?

Comment: No, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we remove the last a row $b$ from the matrix $A$. Then
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} B \\ b\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$AA^*=\begin{pmatrix}BB^* & Bb^* \\ bB^* & bb^*\end{pmatrix}$$
It follows that $BB^*$ is a $n\times n$ submatrix of $AA^*$.

The [Cauchy's interlacing theorem](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2004.11920060) holds to  $AA^*$ and $BB^*$. See also this [wikipedia text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem). It follows that
$$\lambda_{n+1}({A}{A}^*)\leq \lambda_n({B}{B}^*)\leq \cdots \leq \lambda_2({A}{A}^*)\leq \lambda_1({B}{B}^*)\leq  \lambda_1({A}{A}^*).$$

You can repeat the argument removing the lats column of $b_1$ of $B$, say
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} B_1&b_1\end{pmatrix},$$
if you consider the matrix $B^*B$ and the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix ${B_1}^*B_1$, you see that
$$\lambda_{n+1}({A}{A}^*)\leq \lambda_{n-1}({B_1}{B}_1^*)\leq \lambda_{n-1}({B}{B}^*)\leq \cdots \leq \lambda_1({B_1}{B}_1^*)\leq \lambda_1({B}{B}^*)\leq  \lambda_1({A}{A}^*).$$

You can repeat the argument and remove the entire matrix $E^T$, and use the equality $\sigma_i(A)=\lambda_i(A^*A)=\lambda_i(AA^*)$.

**Remark:** Please see this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382142/interlacing-theorem-on-singular-values/4306448#4306448) that I found with SearchOnMath when I search for "\(A^*A+a_1^*a_1\)  with \(a_1\) a row matrix singular values".

Comment: Thank you so much! This definitely solves my problem